# Can't upload larage size pdf file in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with uploading files larger than 1MB. My website is already published online. When I try to upload small pdf files , it uploads successfully, but I when try to upload pdf files larger than 2 or 5MB I get this error. knowing that I allowed uploading more than 100MB size.

> Undefined index: file

It tells me that the error is in this line :

```
if ($_FILES['file']['type'] ==  'application/pdf' or $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'application/msword'  or $_FILES['file']['type'] ==  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'  )
```

This is my code :

```
 public function uploadfile(Request $request){
        $destination_path = 'files/';
        if ($_FILES['file']['type'] ==  'application/pdf' or $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'application/msword'  or $_FILES['file']['type'] ==  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'  ) {

            $type = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
//            dd($type);
            $name = uniqid() . "." . $type;
            $target_path = $destination_path . $name;

            $success = 0;
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
                $success = 1;
            }
        }

        // $output will be converted into JSON

        if ($success) {

            $upload = new Uploads(array(

                'name' => $_POST['name'],
                'link' => $name ,
                'status' => 0 ,

            ));

            $upload->save();

            $json['files'][] = array(
                'name' => $name,
                'id' => $upload->id,
                'url' => $target_path,
                'message' => 'Uploaded successfully'
            );
            return  response()->json($json);
        } else {
            $output = array("success" => false, "error" => "Failure!");
        }

        header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
        echo json_encode($output);

    }
```

Comment: Did you check the upload_max_size ?

Comment: Open the **php.ini** file. Find these lines in the **php.ini** file and replace it following numbers `upload_max_filesize = 64M`
Save the changes and try uploading the file again